# using drush for upgrade drupal 6 to 7 - create alias problem

Tags: drush

I want to use drush for upgrade my drupal 6 to drupal7. i read this document. i have a problem with create alias. i have been doing this

1- create a subdomain in my plesk (create sub.domain.com)

2- go to /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs and download [this](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!examples!example.aliases.drushrc.php/7) file and rename this to "aliases.drushrc.php"

3- remove aliases.drushrc.php content and replace with

`<?php
$aliases['sub'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub',
  'uri' => 'sub.domain.com',
);
?>`

4- run command: drush @sub status and i get this error:

`The drush command '@sub status' could not be found.  Run`drush cache-clear drush`to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the Drupal root is a valid place to store alias files, Drush will not be able to find the alias records described there until the Drupal root as been specified.  Therefore, `drush @sub status` has a chicken-and-egg problem; you want to use @sub to specify the Drupal root, but Drush won't load the alias file that defines @sub until the Drupal site it is defined in is bootstrapped.

To resolve this problem, move your aliases file to $HOME/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php.  Once you do that, then your status command will work.

You may define your 'onward' alias either in $HOME/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php, or in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/aliases.drushrc.php, per your preference.

Answer (score 0):

[Drush Site Upgrade](http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup) needs to be installed first.

You can download the module and upload it to drush/commands/core folder.
Now you will be able to run this command

If you are getting some problems when Drush tries to create a new database, create it first and enter it in the alias file.

Comment: The error message here is deceptive; although Drush is saying "command not found", what it is really reporting is that @sub is not found.  Once the problem reported in the question has been resolved per my answer, then you are correct: `drush dl drush_sup` should be used to download Drush Site Upgrade to $HOME/.drush.  Using drush dl to install a Drush extension will always clear the Drush commandfile cache; if you install an extension manually (e.g. via wget or cp), then you should run `drush cc drush`) afterwards.